# How to find out an equation's roots in R?

Tags: r

I have a R equation like this:

```
f<-function(x){
    abs(x-0.2)=1.96*sqrt(x*(1-x)/300)
}
```

Is there a built-in function to find the roots of it for this in R?

Comment: I don't think that function is syntactically correct (have you been able to use it to evaluate f(x)?). You might want to rewrite it (though that might not be possible). Then use something like the uniroot function: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/uniroot.html

Comment: as I commented on a now-deleted version of this that was migrated from StackExchange: following up on the uniroot suggestion (e.g. search on SO for answers involving "[r] uniroot" would help show that you were trying to get help on a specific problem, not just asking people to solve problems for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method for advancing your understanding would be to plot the two expressions on the LHS and the RHS for various values and plot them together:

```
plot( seq(-2, 2, by=.01), abs(seq(-2, 2, by=.01)-0.2) ,ylim=c(-2,2) ,type="l")
lines( seq(-10, 10, by=.1), 1.96*sqrt(seq(-10, 10, by=.1) *(1-seq(-10, 10, by=.1))/300) )
Warning message:
In sqrt(seq(-10, 10, by = 0.1) * (1 - seq(-10, 10, by = 0.1))/300) :
  NaNs produced
```

[image]

This can be quite helpful in setting up a `uniroot` solution. Notice that I didn't need to have the sequences be the same in the `plot` and `lines` calls, but one would need the sequences to match in the x and y arguments to 'plot' and 'line'. I started out plotting points but switched to lines and started out with a range of -10 to 10. Further zooming should be possible.